# Google Apps Script- Loop Through Nested JSON Response and Set Values to Spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script, I am connecting to a service via OAuth2. I get a JSON response and parse it with `JSON.parse(response.getContentText());` so it logs something like so:

```
{Results=[{Id=45364743, Description=null, Name=Math I , IsActive=true}, 
          {Id=45364768, Description=null, Name=Math II, IsActive=true}]}
```

Using the following code, I have previously taken JSON responses and written them successfully to Google Sheets. However, this time the FOR loop does not run because `dataSet` does not have a `length`. I am guessing that is because everything is nested under "Results".

```
function getService2() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data');
var key = 'kjeu7hjf7873alkjhehjhfayuluoojsds'
var options = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + key,
        api_key:                   key,
    }
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);  
var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
var dataSet = dataAll;
Logger.log(dataSet)
var rows = [],
  data;
for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) 
if (  dataSet.length > 0.0){
  data = dataSet[i];
rows.push([data.Id, data.Name, data.IsActive ]); //your JSON entities here

dataRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, rows.length , 2);
dataRange.setValues(rows);
}}
```

How would I determine the length of the parsed JSON response (i.e. "dataSet") to run the loop and write to the sheet?

Comment: Replace `var dataSet = dataAll;` with `var dataSet = dataAll.Results;`

Comment: That was it! Any idea why the "rows.length" grows by 1 for each loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed some bugs and edited to fix them. Your `for` loop had issues. You were writing into sheet on every iteration which is not performant.

```
function getService2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data');
  var key = 'kjeu7hjf7873alkjhehjhfayuluoojsds';
  var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + key,
      api_key: key
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var dataSet = dataAll.Results;
  Logger.log(dataSet);
  var rows = [],
    data;
  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.Id, data.Name, data.IsActive]); //your JSON entities here
  }
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, rows.length, 3).setValues(rows);
}
```